# Answers vs discussion

Tags: discussion, support

Are there any guidelines as to when an answer becomes a discussion.  I am new to StackOverflow and one of the questions I attempted to answer seems to be heading towards a discussion rather than a straightforward answer.  I did check answers on this board, but did not find help on this particular point.

Comment: Can you post a link to the question.

Comment: @ChrisF: I went through his profile, and I believe he's referring to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690840/how-can-i-model-this-usage-scenario/3691337#3691337).

Comment: There's always http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com if you wish to engage in a real time discussion with other users.

Comment: This proto-discussion has come to a natural end. @ChrisF the question was the one @BoltClock picked up on.

Comment: @Yi Jiang - thanks, but real time discussions are often not an option for me - I live on a boat; travel frequently; and am often in locations where I cannot get mobile connections.

Comment: IMHO a related issue is answers that make a good point but in no way answer the question (or even only partly answer the question). Once an answer is accepted, it is OK to up vote these responses, but voting for them beforehand means the question moves off the Unanswered questions view :-( It would be nice if we could "Up vote as a Comment".